# What's the programming language of BLOGGER templates?

Tags: html, css, xml, blogger, blogs

I want to know how I can make my own blogger template to use for my blog. When I open HTML editor from Blogger the code seems to be a strange mix of HTML, XML and CSS. I also sometimes notice variables and other things. I want to know what language I could use to make a responsive website with CSS styles. I used to use pre-created templates from the internet but it seems better to get my own design and be able to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Blogger.com](https://www.blogger.com/about/?r=2) which is a content management system that used itself for managing its content. Due to the related news, their backend (to see what backend is you can check the following link: [Learn to become backend developer](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/modern-backend-developer-in-2018-6b3f7b5f8b9)) is written in **python** and the frontend (to learn more about frontend you should check this out: [Learn to become frontend developer](https://medium.com/@kamranahmedse/modern-frontend-developer-in-2018-4c2072fa2b9c)) used **HTML5**, **CSS3**, and various open-source libraries of **JavaScript**.

But if you want to know what language you need to use to create a blog, I would say anything you feel more convenient with, that doesn't really matter to use which technology or framework, you can use blogger itself or other CMS creators like, **WordPress**, **Drupal** and so on, and also yes, you can build one from scratch with trending frontend CSS frameworks like [these ones](https://medium.com/sleithdylan/5-popular-css-frameworks-65cbd3d7a576) and JS libraries like [these ones](https://medium.com/cuelogic-technologies/top-3-best-javascript-frameworks-for-2019-3e6d21eff3d0) and at last backend frameworks like [these ones](https://medium.com/@shahroznawaz/best-backend-frameworks-to-build-your-next-web-application-2f89f08f34e3) mentioned here.

Also, you can find the best practices and examples in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) or [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/) and some other known ones.

Answer (score -1):

Blogger is written with Python in backend. Front-end it's use HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
Blogger used XHTML(XML + Html). As you know that XML is Extensible Markup Language.

Blogger provide it's own data: and <b:> (blogger) namespaces. That is used to for data replacement on server side. Even it avoid conflicts with frontend end html tags.

Script runs for each post, page and appropriate data is patched to destination (b: & data: )

Archive and index are also created. ( the basic of web site)

So we can say that blogger does use **XHTML Scripting** for generating the website web pages. Officially we will never find thae name that which language is being used  by blogger in front end. ( user side )